# List items clickable and opening of detailed planet page by URL building

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of planets (see code below) and am now trying to add a new part to my app. Every planet name in the list should be clickable. When clicked a planet detail page with detailed info for every planet should appear.

For example: It should append to the URL `https://swapi.dev/api/ + planets/1`

This is the API that I am using: https://swapi.dev/

---

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            planets: [],
            filteredPlanets: []
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
        let planetssearchlist = this.state.planets.filter(planet => {
             if(planet.name){
                if(planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true 
                }   
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            filteredPlanets: planetssearchlist
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let planetslist = response.data.results;
            this.setState({planets: planetslist, filteredPlanets: planetslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error with the planets load charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (

        <div>
            <h1>Star Wars Planets</h1>

            <form>
                <input placeholder="searchbar" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
            </form>

            {
                this.state.filteredPlanets.map((planet,i) => (
                        <p key={i}>{planet.name}</p>
                ))   
            }

        </div>    

        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem

Comment: well the problem is that I don't know how to get this done or how to start coding for this specific work stream